# How to store error statues and messages in NGXS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, state-management, ngxs

This might be a somewhat open question, but I has to do with best practices when using NGXS.
I was wondering which approach would be best for error handling and what to keep in each State in a typical NGXS app.
I know there are different approaches at error handling, but this goes a little beyond that. I realize I have at least these options:

1. Store **everything** inside the store, that is, every request error and error message possible coming from the API
2. Store only the data coming from the API, that is, without errors (like 200s) having all the logging and operations on this data and affecting state whenever needed.
3. Something in between, keeping some errors, like those affecting several components (i.e. app state as a whole) and just throwing errors to the components for them to handle (display error messages)
4. I did think of another possibility, doing something like No. 1, but storing all errors in a map or similar, so I don't have my state models polluted with all error the possible error statuses and error messages.

Is this a valid question? Or am I missing something? or maybe misunderstanding some ngxs concept? Do some of these approaches seem like a "best practice"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are so many spelling errors in this, it is hard to understand what you are asking. Fix that.

Comment: You're right. I've corrected the question. Not being an native speaker does not excuse spelling errors. I should have reviewed the question before posting. Sorry about that.

Comment: A question to ask is are you planning on doing anything with these errors? In our app, using ngrx, we do have an error field in our state. However it is just there for us to be able to set the error state and that's it

Comment: That's it, I do not plan on using the errors, they are meant to give some feedback to user actions. That's why I thought I should not keep them. But isn't the idea of state management to keep all things in a single place? why bother using a state management solution for things like lists of records (like datatables and such) and other data if they're meant to be shown once... maybe go to another page where you add a record, go back and reload the list... so it feels like I'm doing the right thing, but at the same time I'm not.

Comment: I think it's more a questing of error handling. Central vs per action. As for showing the error message to the user, I rather do that out of the state, so that it doesn't deal with things that are out of it's scope.